# Service Fabric with Microsoft Nano nodes

Tags: service, server, azure-service-fabric, nano-server

Is it possible to build a standalone Service Fabric cluster where Microsoft Nano is used as nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean for on-premise deployment. If it is then the answer is no as the minimum requirement wont be met.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-standalone-deployment-preparation

Prerequisites for each machine that you want to add to the cluster:+

- A minimum of 16 GB of RAM is recommended.
- A minimum of 40 of GB available disk space is recommended.
- A 4 core or greater CPU is recommended.